# Can I simplified the operator(addition/multiplication) overload via C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, operator-overloading, mingw-w64

I make a class about Complex addition,but I found it was kinda tedious to write the overload function. 
my code(c++11) is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
class complex{
public:
    complex(double real,double imag);
    complex();
    friend complex operator +(const double &m, const complex &origin);
    friend complex operator +(const complex &origin, const double &m);
    double real;
    double imag;
};
complex::complex(double real,double imag):real(real),imag(imag){;};
complex::complex():real(0),imag(0){;};
complex operator +(const double &m,const complex &origin){
    complex p;
    p.real=origin.real+m;
    p.imag=origin.imag;
    return p;
}
complex operator +(const complex &origin,const double &m){
    return m+origin;
}




int main() {
    complex com(1,2);
    com=3.+com;
    com=com+3.;
    return 0;
}
```

can I do the addition of Complex with one operator function by using my class(anyway I DON'T WANNA use standard library of )? thanks.

Comment: Just curious, why do you not want to use `std::complex`?

Comment: Anyway, the answer is "yes" if you want to restrict how you use `operator+` to only be in one direction, but this is considered a bad design principle (binary operators should be symmetric). So in the end, it's fine to leave it as two functions, one calling the other. As a final aside, adding many overloads for a function is a very common practice in C++, so it's best to embrace that sooner rather than later.

Comment: @AndyG std::complex isn't good enough for me. and I wanna make a more readable style of class (even though I can use inheritance of standard library) :)

Comment: Making a more readable style is a noble goal. However, note that there are very few standard library classes you can/should inherit from due to lack of virtual destructors. If you do go that route, just be careful about how you use the derived class.

Comment: *std::complex isn't good enough for me* An awful lot lot of awfully smart people has worked on `std::complex` for way too long in order to make it absolutely perfect. Are you hoping to outdo them with a little help from stackoverflow community? I wish you lots of luck, you will need it.